# Competing risk data

Tags: r, survival, exponential-distribution

I want to simulate survival time for two competitive events using `R`. Consider that there are no censored data, and the survival time for each event has exponential distribution with rate 0.25 and 0.1 respectively. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user29237. Are you just asking for code? Note that that would be off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)). Please clarify your question & make sure it is appropriate for CV; if not, this Q may have to be closed.

Comment: I would simulate y1 from the first exponential distribution, y2 from the second exponential distribution, and I would store the minimum between y1 and y2 along with a binary variable indicating which event occurred (1 if y1 < y2 and 2 if y2 < y1).

Comment: Is this for some subject? The relevant function for simulating exponentials is `rexp`

Answer (score 2):

Using Ocram's suggestion:

```
n = 1000

y1 = rexp(n,rate=.25)
y2 = rexp(n,rate=.1)

events = ifelse(y1<y2,1,2)
```